# Stop window.location to if deeplink to app works

Tags: javascript

So I have the following button on the site.

```
<img class="openApp" onclick="loadAppOrPlayStore();" src="img/open_in_app.png" width="35px"/>
```

I then have this function,

```
  function loadAppOrPlayStore() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var item = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    window.location.href = 'URL' + item;
    setTimeout("window.location = 'URL_TO_PLAY_STORE';", 1000);
  }
```

The problem is, even though I have the application, the application does work. When I go back into the browser on the phone, the URL_TO_PLAY_STORE is there. Can I stop that from happening if the application is loading?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store program codes as functions instead of strings, like this:

```
setTimeout(()=>{window.location = 'URL_TO_PLAY_STORE';}, 1000)
```

I hope that this will help you!

Comment: This still loads the play store in browser.